# Curve approaching itself is an immersed but not an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

The curve given below (from John Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, 2.ed., p.111) is frequently used as an example of an immersed submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ which is not an embedded submanifold. The arrow means that the curve approaches itself up to an arbitrarily small distance without meeting it. As a parametrization $\gamma:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$, the curve is clearly an injective immersion, since there is no crossing point and the velocity vector never vanishes.

As a set of points, i.e. as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, the curve $\gamma(\mathbb R)$ shall be endowed with the final topology with respect to $\gamma$, which is the topology induced by the natural topology of $\mathbb R$, and with respect to this topology every point of the curve, including p, has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R$. Thus, the curve is a topological 1-manifold. Furthermore, $(\gamma(\mathbb R),\gamma^{-1},1)$ is a chart giving $\gamma(\mathbb R)$ a smooth structure.

Question 1: What I don't see clearly is why this smooth structure makes the inclusion map $\iota:\gamma(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R^2 $ an immersion, this being the requirement for $\gamma(\mathbb R)$ to be an immersed submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.

The requirement for the curve to be an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ is that, $\gamma(\mathbb R)$ this time being endowed with the subspace topology of $\mathbb R^2$, the inclusion map $\iota$ is a topological and therefore smooth embedding, which means that $\iota$ induces a homeomorphism $\varphi: \gamma(\mathbb R) \to \iota(\gamma(\mathbb R))$.

Question 2: It is unclear to me, what precisely is the argument showing that such a homeomorphism is not induced in the case of this curve. I think it has to do with open neighborhoods of the point p within the respective topologies, but I cannot find out what exactly it is.

Thanks in advance for help.

[image]

Comment: For the second: Show that $\iota^{-1}$ fails to be continuous at $p$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thanks a lot for your hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

If $G = \gamma(\mathbb R) \subset \mathbb R^2$ as usual receives the subspace topology, then the function $\bar \gamma : \mathbb R \stackrel{\gamma}{\to}  G$ is a continuous bijection, but not a homeomorphism (see Question 2). But we can endow  $G$ with a unique new topology $\tau$ making $\bar \gamma : \mathbb R \to G_\tau = (G,\tau)$ a homeomorphism (this can be done for each bijection without any further assumptions). Next $G_\tau$ can be endowed with a unique smooth structure making $\bar \gamma$ a diffeomorphism. Obviously $G_\tau$ is a copy of $\mathbb R$ which lies in $\mathbb R^2$ **on the level sets**, but is **not a subspace** (or a submanifold). of $\mathbb R^2$.

We know that $\gamma : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ is an immersion and $\bar \gamma$ is a diffeomorphism, thus
$$\iota = \gamma \circ \bar \gamma^{-1} : G_\tau \to \mathbb R^2$$
is an immersion.

Question 2:

You ask why $\bar \gamma : \mathbb R \to  G$ is not a homeomorphism. Consider a point $x \in G$ lying right of $p$. Then $G \setminus \{x\}$ is connected (as a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$), but $\mathbb R \setminus \{ \bar \gamma^{-1}(x)\}$ is not connected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precise answer, which has clarified the situation quite a lot for me. The only thing remaining unclear to me is the last sentence of your first paragraph, the one you highlighted. Apart from the fact that I don't know what "lying on the level sets" means (probably I have not read far enough in my textbook yet), I see that with respect to the new topology G is not a topological subspace of $ \mathbb{R}^2$, whereas it is with the subspace topology. But according to Lee's definition, p.108, with respect to the new topology G is an immersed submanifold of $ \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @RolandSalz The higlighted text wants to say that the image of $\gamma$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$  (which is trivial). We have two different topologies on the image: The subspace topology and $\tau$. The subspace $G$ is not a manifold, but the space $G_\tau$ has the structure of a smooth manifold making $\iota$ an immersion. In my opinion the concept of an immersed submanfold is not very useful because we get an object which topologically has nothing to do with   the ambient space.

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to think about how the term "locally" changes when you view things on $\mathbb R$ and on $\gamma(\mathbb R)$.

To make things completely concrete, I will take $\gamma \colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ to be $\gamma(t) = (\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} t),\frac{1}{2}\sin(\pi t))$, then of course $\gamma$ is not injective on all of $\mathbb R$, as it describes a figure 8 on its side any interval of length $4$. However, if we restrict to, say, $(-1,2)$ then $\gamma(t)$ describes the locus below:
[image]

As $(-1,2)$ is of course diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ it is essentially the situation you consider.

Now for any $t_0\in (-1,2)$ an open neighbourhood of $t_0$ is an open interval. Moreover, the same of is true for $\gamma(-1,2)$ *locally on the source* $(-1,\pi)$, that is, given $t_0$, there is an open neighbourhood $I$ of $t_0\in(-1,2)$ and a neighbourhood $U\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ of $\gamma(t_0)$ and coordinates on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\gamma$ takes the form $\gamma(t) = (t,0)$. (This is what the immersion condition, i.e. the injectivity of the derivative, gets you thanks to the inverse function theorem).

The problem, however, is when you consider things *locally on the target* $\mathbb R^2$: an open neighbourhood of $\gamma(0)=(0,0)$, which is the intersection of an open neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ with $\gamma(-1,\pi)$, is homeomorphic to the letter T. This is not homeomorphic to an interval (e.g. removing the origin leaves a space with 3 connected components, not $2$), thus $\gamma(-1,\pi)$ is not an immersed submanifold.

Comment: Your answer gives a nice example of a parametrization. Thanks a lot for the clarifications.